# Necesito una mano para darle forma a este proyecto

Tags: html5

Es mi primera vez trabajando con algo así, quiero "actualizar" el diseño de esta pagina pero no se si es porque no conozco mucho de HTML o es que estoy super loco y enredado con estos problemas...

El primero es que no puedo colocar el icono en la cabecera de ninguna forma y ya no se que hacer...

El segundo es que quiero alinear en la barra de navegación un logo pero siempre que lo coloco me desordena todos los demás iconos y textos... anexo el codigo y unas capturas ...[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title><?php _tradu("BoomKash - Envie dinero a donde quiera y a quien quiera!"); ?></title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="dist/img/favicon.ico">
    <!-- Font Awesome Icons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
  <!-- IonIcons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/adminlte.min.css">
  <!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
  <!-- Navbar -->
  <nav class="main-header navbar navbar-expand navbar-red navbar-dark">
    <img src="dist/img/logo.png" class="logo">
    <!-- Left navbar links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-widget="pushmenu" href="#" role="button"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
        <h3 class="m-0 text-white"></h3>
      </li>
      
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Right navbar links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
         
      <!-- Notifications Dropdown Menu -->
      
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg dropdown-menu-right">
          <span class="dropdown-item dropdown-header">7 Notifications</span>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
            <i class="fas fa-envelope mr-2"></i> 4 new messages
            <span class="float-right text-muted text-sm">3 mins</span>
          </a>

          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
            <i class="fas fa-file mr-2"></i> 3 new reports
            <span class="float-right text-muted text-sm">2 days</span>
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-footer">See All Notifications</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-widget="control-sidebar" data-slide="true" href="#" role="button"><i
            class="fas fa-briefcase"></i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- /.navbar -->

  <!-- Main Sidebar Container -->
  <aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-white elevation-4">
    <!-- Brand Logo -->
    <a href="index3.html" class="brand-link">
      <img src="dist/img/AdminLTELogo.png" alt="AdminLTE Logo" class="brand-image img-default elevation-3"
           style="opacity: .8">
      <span class="brand-text font-weight-light">BoomKash</span>
    </a>

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="sidebar">
      <!-- Sidebar user panel (optional) -->
      <div class="user-panel mt-3 pb-3 mb-3 d-flex">
```

Disculpen lo novato

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar lo que yo haría primero es ajustar las dimensiones de mi logo con CSS al tamaño final que quiero que tenga. Eso a mí me ayudaría a no estresarme con el logotipo gigante ahí en medio.

Luego probaría o bien a encapsular el logo dentro de un div, que es un elemento de tipo "block" o a convertir el elemento "img" en un "block" para poder posicionarlo mejor, porque de forma predeterminada es "inline" y eso suele dar problemas a veces.

Por otro lado lo mismo es una neura mía pero me pone muy nervioso ver la etiqueta `<head>` y no ver la etiqueta `<body>` en todo el código que has mandado.

Comment: hombre la etiqueta <body> no la inserte porque donde tengo los problemas no es allí... Pero gracias igual